# osascript dialog box is blocking.

Tags: applescript, script

I'm using osascript to display dialog box from bash script, but it's blocking the script, until i press the 'ok' button.

I wonder if there's a way to make this display window asynchronous.

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "'"${msg}"'"'
```

This means that the script will continue running and the osascript will run on the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ampersand (`&`) at the end of the line. Quote from [bashitout](http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html):

> A single ampersand & can often be found at the end of a command.
>
> ```
>  ./myscript.py &
> ```
>
> This trailing ampersand directs the shell to run the command in the background, that is, it is forked and run in a separate sub-shell, as a job, asynchronously. The shell will immediately return the return status of 0 for true and continue as normal, either processing further commands in a script or returning the cursor focus back to the user in a Linux terminal.